# Convert 3D models to patent digrams

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, 3ds

I want to convert 3dsmax file to patent diagrams in different perspectives. I am new to 3dsmax, and i want to know if there is any method to export it to line drawings like the ones that is available in patents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A toon shader is typically used for this.
Use the 'Ink 'n Paint' shader on your models, and set it for the kind of look you are after.